# Агрегация между классами

Tags: c++, классы

Объясните пожалуйста понятие агрегации между классами. Например, если есть два класса, classx и classy и они находятся в отношении агрегации, то как это реализовывается в коде. Полезным будут и какие-то понятные примеры из интернета, я не нашел ничего толкового.

Comment: Агрегация - это когда все в одной куче., то есть групповуха:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Агрегация — это отношение между объектами, при котором

- один объект содержит другой как часть, но
- внешний объект не является *владельцем* внутреннего.

Это означает, что окончание жизненного цикла внешнего объекта не означает автоматически окончание жизненного цикла внутреннего объекта.

Пример: страна аггрегирует своих граждан (то есть, они являются её частью). Но не уничтожает их при распаде страны.

```
class citizen
{
};

class country
{
    // используем указатель, чтобы предотвратить копирование сущностей (у нас не может быть
    // одновременно два "экземпляра" одного и того же гражданина), а также владение ими.
    unordered_set<citizen*> population;

public:
    void add_citizen(citizen* pc)
    {
        population.insert(pc);
    }
    voit remove_citizen(citizen* pc)
    {
        population.erase(pc);
    }

    ~country()
    {
        // не удаляем граждан, пусть живут
    }
};
```

Comment: А если он является владельцем тогда как это называется?

Comment: @Cerbo: композиция?

Answer (score 2):

[Агрегация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) это когда объекты одного класса входят в объекты другого ( то есть, отношение типа “часть-целое”).